# Proving independence of functions of independent variables.

Tags: probability, random-variables

How would you go about proving that two random variables are independent, when the variables are not both discrete or continuous? Also how would you then prove functions of these random variables and independent?

(I know how to prove this in the case where two random variables and both discrete or continuous.)

Thanks

Comment: What do you specifically mean by "discrete"? Sampled? If that is the case sample the other function as well, keeping in mind the nyquist criterion. Then just calculate the correlation. That will asses the statistical independency (but not necessarily whether the functions are related).

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to prove that $P(X\leq x,Y\leq y)=P(X\leq x)P(Y\leq y)$, or in terms of CDF's $F_{X,Y}(x,y)=F_X(x)F_Y(y)$.

Discrete or continuous is not really relevant in this.

If $X,Y$ are independent random variables and $f,g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ are measurable functions then: $$P(f(X)\in A,g(Y)\in B)=P(X\in f^{-1}(A),Y\in g^{-1}(B))=P(X\in f^{-1}(A))P(Y\in g^{-1}(B)=P(f(X)\in A)P(g(Y)\in B)$$

for measurable sets $A,B$.